# Rewrite rule in htaccess is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect the url:
'**mysiteurl/Actors/as23sderd/1**' to '**mysiteurl/cataImages.php?c=Actors&p=1**'

using the following htacess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ cataImages.php?c=$2&p=$3
```

But it is not redirecting now.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ cataImages.php?c=$1&p=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ cataImages.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```